# Equivalence of Observable.Do for Enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerable

Theres a **Do** method in System.Reactive to a execute a mutator for each item in the sequence.

Is there any equivalent method for IEnumerable either in standard library or third parties like [morelinq](https://morelinq.github.io/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ query operators are generally meant to be free from side-effects. You could just use a `foreach` loop to "do" your thing.

Or do it in a `Select` or `Where` method if you don't care about side effects:

```
enumerable.Select(x => { /*do something here */ return x; })
```

For a `List<T>`, there is a `ForEach` extension method that can be used to execute an `Action<T>` for each element.

Comment: The Do method executes the action as parte of the pipeline. ForEach does this for a materialized list, that isn't what I need. I need a pull-version of it.

Comment: I know, hence the "For a `List<T>`..." in the answer. So use any of my first two suggestions?